# How do I search the package lists of old Ubuntu releases?

Tags: apt, package-management, apt-cache

I usually search for packages using `apt-cache` (e.g. `apt-cache search 'flash player'`) or by using the search functionality on https://packages.ubuntu.com.

Now suppose I wish to search the package list of an old Ubuntu release such as Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin. How can I do it? `apt-cache search ...` only searches the packages available for the version of Ubuntu I am using. https://packages.ubuntu.com only searches a few of the latest releases.

I suppose I could download the package list from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/, but what do I do with the package list to be able to search it? I prefer using something similar to `apt-cache search ...`, but I do not want to mess up my existing packages just because I want to search an old package list.

Comment: @Terrance I am not interested in installing packages from old releases. I only want to **search** the package lists of old releases.

Comment: @Terrance So it's not possible to use `apt-cache search` to search old package lists without messing up my current installation's package lists?

Comment: @Terrance Okay. Once I download the package list file (`Package.gz`) and un-gzip it, is there a better tool than `grep` for searching the file?

Comment: @Terrance But the problem with `grep` is that it will also return hits in the "Depends" field.

Comment: @Terrance I asked about chroot in another question, but that is an entirely unrelated question. This question has nothing to do with the other one. They are completely separate. In this question, I want to search the package lists from old releases. Only **search**. The chroot thing is for a completely unrelated problem.

Answer (score 4):

For online search I would recommend to use the https://repology.org service.

If we search for *xbattle*

> [image: search for xbattle on repology.org]

as the package of interest

> [image: search results for xbattle on repology.org]

it will show [the following](https://repology.org/project/xbattle/versions):

> [image: xbattle @ repology.org]

So this package was last available in 12.04 LTS. If you click on the *xbattle* then you will be transferred to the [launchpad project page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xbattle).